# Cookies set and working but can't be seen in chrome dev tools

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cookies, google-chrome-devtools

I have a weird issue where I'm setting a cookie in my controller. I can print the contents of the cookie with a `puts` statement but when I look for the cookie in the chrome dev tools it cant be seen.

Any Idea what would cause this behavior? The cookie is clearly there as the `puts` works on every page reload.

In controller action `A`:

```
cookies['cookiename'] = {
      value: 'a value'
    }
```

In controller action `B`:

```
puts cookies.to_h
```

prints `{"cookiename"=>"a value"}`

but in Chrome I see nothing:

[image]

I should note this is a rails API project and I have enabled cookies middleware and included `ActionController::Cookies` in my controller.

Comment: If you look at the network tab, does it show `set-cookie` under headers? I know it's silly but it doesn't make sense that it's not working.

Comment: try also this other setrings, next to value {expires: 1.month.from_now, same_site: :none, secure: true}